# How to connect an oracle database in visual studio

Tags: oracle, visual-studio-2015

I already downloaded the oracle developer tools for VS, then I tried connecting HR to Visual studio with this configuration:

[my configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cshB1.png)

but gives me this error:

ORA-12514, TNS:listener does not currently know of service requested in
connect descriptor

how do i resolve it?

Comment: So you also installed the oracle database server on your workstation? Because this TNS entry is pointing to the current workstation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your configuration specifies to request a connection to service 'orcl'.  But the error message says the database listener (the process responsible for handling the connection request) does not know of any database services 'orcl'.  To fully debug, we'd need to see the output of the command 'lsnrctl status', as executed on the database server machine.  Most like cause is that the database itself is not started, and thus is not registered to the listener.